# Any function that can add rownames and colnames into excel file?

Tags: r, xlsx

I am using write.xlsx function from "xlsx" package.

```
for (i in 1:noctry) {
    for (l in 1:3) {
        write.xlsx(tab110rev[i,,], file=paste(title[l],l,".xlsx"), sheetName = country_code[i],
           col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
    }
}
```

noctry stands for number of countries and its 53 
countrylist is a list of countries with country codes which are numbers.
tab110rev is an array that has the structure of array(value, c(country, industry, year))

The result is each sheet by each country, rows representing ISIC code, columns representing years.

I want to add column names and row names to the excel file, but as you can see, "col.names" and "row.names" option is a logical.
Is there any option or function I can add a row name and column when writing an xlsx file?

I can add the name by loading the xlsx file I have just wrote and add row name and column name and save it back but I just want to know if there is a function that can write xlsx and add row names and column names at the same time.

I have tried the following code and the rownames just appear as numbers and colnames and X1, X2, X3...

```
for (i in 1:noctry) {
for (l in 1:3) {
rownames(tab110rev[i,l,,]) <- c(isic_code)
colnames(tab110rev[i,l,,]) <- c(year)
write.xlsx(tab110rev[i,l,,], file=paste(title[l],l,".xlsx"), sheetName = country_code[i],
           col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=TRUE)
}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this work: `col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE`?

Comment: I have to add specific row name and column name which is a vector of characters. If I use col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE than the row names will be numbers and column names will be V1 V2 V3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define the row names and column names as strings and use col.names=TRUE and row.names=TRUE:

```
library(WriteXLS)
x = as.data.frame(replicate(2, rnorm(2))
colnames(x) = c("test", "test1")
rownames(x) = c("test", "test1")

WriteXLS(x, ExcelFileName="temp.xls", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: The problem here is the data I am using to write xlsx file is not two dimensional. It's a array with 4 dimensions so I can't just use colnames and rownames function directly to a 4 dimension array.

Comment: If your data frame has n dimensions, you can just expand the answer above accordingly. Please edit your question providing a reproducible example, including your data structure.

Comment: I have edited my question. I reduced it to 3 dimension for simplicity. "rownames(tab110rev[i,,k]) <- c(country_code)"  with for loop would work?

Comment: Possibly, impossible to say without knowing what your input data frame looks like.

Comment: I changed dimnames before writing an xlsx file. Problem solved!